# need help creating a using a derived textbox class in c#

Tags: c#

Ive done a bunch of tutorials already but hoping someone can help me.  I am trying to create my own textbox class, derived from the base textbox class.

All i am trying to do is set a specific style for my derived class.

Inside the below, how do i set the text, text colour and background colour so that when i call MyTextBox newbox = new MyTextbox, i get a textbox styled just how i want it?

```
class MyTextBox:TextBox

    {            
      MyTextBox basetextbox = new MyTextBox

      //somehow need to add in the textbox properties here

    }
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: You can just access the properties directly, no need to instantiate a base class object.
Which platform are you working on? What type of a project? Windows forms? Silverlight? WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the class constructor. Simply assign a value to the selected base class property.

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{            
     public MyTextBox()
     {
         //base.PropertyName = value;
     }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! easy when you know how.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ricardinho, just to add to this answer, you should remove the `MyTextBox basetextbox = new MyTextBox` line from your code as you do not what to create another TextBox instance inside your derived class.